# Вывести данные из таблицы

Tags: php, html, чат

Только начал изучать PHP, пытаюсь сделать элементарный чат. Есть блок DIV, где и должен быть сам чат и есть форма nick, text и submit

php код

```
 if(isset($_POST['sent'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['nick'])){
        $nick = htmlspecialchars($_POST['nick']);
        $nick = stripcslashes($nick);
        $nick = trim($nick);
        $text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']);
        $text = stripcslashes($text);
        $text = trim($text);
            include ('bd.php');
            $query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO cat (nick, message) VALUES ('$nick', '$text')");
```

и html

```
 <div id="welcome">
    <h2>Добро пожаловать!</h2>
<div class="chat">
    <p>Here is chat</p>
    <p class="chat_text">
        <?php
            echo $result['nick'].$result['message'];
        ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

" placeholder="Enter your nick">

Как мне сделать так, чтобы данные которые в базе данных, оставались в диве?

Comment: А что такое $result ? видимо должен быть код, который делает select из таблицы, что бы этот result заполнялся данными. И еще рекомендую добавить в таблицу колонку дата сообщения или id постоянно растущий добавить (если его нет, тут не видно) и при выборке из таблицы делать order by по этой колонке, что бы порядок записей сохранялся

Comment: ой, видимо не обвел до конца, result это 
$result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM cat ORDER BY id"));

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array возвращает только одну строку. наверное есть смысл вызывать ее в цикле, для получения всех записей.

Comment: Да, я так и планировал выводить, только вот сам вопрос как? ) Т.е в базу инфа сохраняется, теперь осталось вывести в div, пробовал выводить через jquery, но он выводит только последнее значение.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', 'submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var value = $('input').value();
        $('.chat_text').append(value);
    });
});
```